# JQuery Popup character map

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, character

Does anybody know of a popup 'character map' jquery plugin?  I have a text field and would like the user to be able to insert special characters (easily).  Similar to the TinyMCE plugin.

Comment: copy script of that specific character insertion code from tinymce's jquery version and put it in ur script

Comment: I can answer my own question: http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html

Comment: you should probably put this as your answer and accept it so that it clears from the unanswered list.

Comment: Rob, please add your comment as an answer and accept it to make it more visible :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One I've used and found pretty useful is Special Edit (http://www.ganzogo.com/projects/specialedit). It gives you really good control over what characters you want to appear, and is easily stylable to fit with your site.